# Explanation of how weakify and strongify work in ReactiveCocoa / libextobjc

Tags: reactive-cocoa, libextobjc

I understand that you should use @weakify @strongify to avoid retain cycles but I don't completely understand how they actually achieve this?

Comment: @jamieforrest I noticed you have edited this question.  When I originally asked this question I definitely was referring to ReactiveCocoa in spite of the fact that these macros might originate in libextobjc, in the version I was using they are defined in a header file called RACEXTScope.h this file exists in ReactiveCocoa and is not an external dependency.  I think we should maintain ReactiveCocoa in the title with libextobjc appended rather than replacing it.

Comment: Makes sense. I added it back.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

When writing the question I stared harder at the macro definitions and I think it works as you might guess.

@weakify creates a new weakly referenced variable of the same type you pass in and assigns the original value to it

@strongify creates a variable that matches the original variable but it exists in the local scope and assigns to it the variable created by @weakify

Answer (score 27):

code before preprocess:

```
@weakify(self)
[[self.searchText.rac_textSignal
  map:^id(NSString *text) {
      return [UIColor yellowColor];
  }]
 subscribeNext:^(UIColor *color) {
     @strongify(self)
     self.searchText.backgroundColor = color;
 }];
```

code after preprocess:

```
@autoreleasepool {} __attribute__((objc_ownership(weak))) __typeof__(self) self_weak_ = (self);
    [[self.searchText.rac_textSignal
      map:^id(NSString *text) {
          return [UIColor yellowColor];
      }]
     subscribeNext:^(UIColor *color) {
         @try {} @finally {}
 __attribute__((objc_ownership(strong))) __typeof__(self) self = self_weak_; // 1
 self.searchText.backgroundColor = color;  //2
     }];
```

1: define a new local variable “self”. this will shadow the global one.

2: so here we used the local variable “self”--self_weak_.

tips:

1.if we used self.xxx in block, we should place @strongify(self) over it.

2.don't forget use @weakify(self) to define the variable self_weak_.

（PS: I'm trying to learn English. I hope that you can understand what I'm saying.）

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong- so, if I forgot to put `@strongify(self)` in the block, then the `self` I use in the block is still the original (not shadowed) self, and will be strongly retained? Still quite error-prone :(

Comment: Yes, that sounds about right. We need a a new Obj-C syntax with strongify / weakify built in!

Answer (score 0):

First and foremost, it matters what implementation of `@weakify` & `@strongify` you're using as these aren't part of the standard language.
Assuming you're using the ReactiveCocoa version, here's a nice [article](http://holko.pl/2015/05/31/weakify-strongify/) about what they are and how they work.

Here are a few relevant quotes:

> Even the code **not** written by us can use `self` safely, e.g. `NSAssert` macro.
>   It's still possible to reference the real `self`, by using an `ivar`. It leads to a warning, though, so it's a mistake that's easy to spot
>
> Now, you may ask: what if I forget to use `strongify`? This is a cool part: `weakify` creates a new local variable, so if it's not used at all we get a warning.
>
> As you can imagine, if you forget to use `weakify`, but `strongify` is in its place, the compiler shows an error

Comment: My original question was about reactive cocoa.  The inclusion of libextobjc was as result of an edit by other users who felt this question applied to that case as well,  I cannot say if it does or does not.